# How can I multiply two lists by elements in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I want a function that gets two lists of Int and generate a list of lists, where each list is the result of the product of each element of the first list by the whole second list. Here's an example:

- Definition of the function : `multiplyElements :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]`
- What I want to do:
- List 1: `[1, 2, 3]` and List 2: `[4, 5, 6]`
- Result: `[[4, 5, 6], [8, 10, 12], [12, 15, 18]]`

`

Comment: Hint: first write a function `Int -> [Int] -> [Int]` that multiplies a single integer with a list of integers in the way you described it.

Comment: `multiplyByValue n list = [x*n | x <- list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
module ListsProduct where

-- function which given a number and a list returns a list representing
-- the elements of the list multipled by the number
g :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
g _ [] = []
g a (x:xs) = a*x : g a xs


-- Recursion proceeds by analysing each element of the first list
-- and multiply it by all elements of the second
f :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
f [] _ = [[]]
f (x:xs) b = g x b : f xs b
```

Comment: And incidentally, looking at the simplified code makes it particularly clear that we are just reimplementing `map` here. There's nothing wrong with doing that for practice, but a real solution would not use any explicit recursion at all.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the support guys, here's my resolution:

```
multiplyByValue :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
multiplyByValue n list = [x*n | x <- list]

multiplyLists :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
multiplyLists list1 list2 = [multiplyByValue x list2 | x <- list1]
```

Comment: Here's a fun one: `multiplyElements = flip (map . flip (map . (*)))`